# How to load component on demand on react-native?

Tags: react-native

My app consists of 500+ screens and 1000+ global components. I need to load a component on demand not load a all components on first time.
For example in 'ReactJS' is **code-spilting** and **react.lazy()** concept is there for this problem.  How it is possible in react-native. How to spilt the component and code in react-native for decrease the app loading time at first time.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

use Dynamic Component Name

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import FooComponent from './foo-component';
import BarComponent from './bar-component';

class MyComponent extends Component {

components = {
    foo: FooComponent,
    bar: BarComponent
};

render() {
   const componentName='foo'
   const TagName = this.components[componentName];
   return <TagName />
}
```

}

Comment: use flatList and render components  on Scroll events